# Chapter number on page header is not updated in LaTeX document

Tags: numbering, header-footer, chapters

I have a small technical problem but I have been unable to find a solution to it so far.

In my thesis document, the chapter numbers that are displayed on page headers are not updated. It keeps on showing "Chapter 1. Some_Chapter_Name" as header. The reason I don't understand is that the chapter numbers on the first page of each chapter is properly incremented but not as page headers for next pages.

Any help will be much appreciated. I am attaching the complete style code for my LaTeX document later on. I believe this is the relevant section to the problem:

**===============
SHORTER VERSION
=================**

```
% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

%% Chapter Heading ---------------
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true,
   plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels, 
   pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

The Thesis template and an example document can be found on http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/.

Comment: Could you please try to make your example a little more minimal? Cut stuff out of the files that isn't related to the problem.

Comment: Hi, I actually posted smaller examples before and the solutions people suggested didn't work..So this time, i have posted the complete version.

Comment: I have added the shorter version of the latex code as well. I hope this will help.

Comment: @Omer: have a look at [what's a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). There's a good way between the two extremes *huge code listing with a lot of irrelevant information* and *code snippet omitting relevant information* : a compilable but reduced copy of your code which still shows the problem.

Comment: Preparing a minimal example is an important part of the detection process.  It might actually eliminate the need to ask a question.  Don't ask the community to do this for you.

Comment: To minimize your example, I suggest first using the lipsum package, rip out the content of your thesis, and make some chapters with enough filler text to show your problem. Next, remove one half of the packages you are using, and check if the problem remains. Repeat until the problem goes away. Then you know the problem lies with the packages you just removed. Put half of them back in … I hope you get the idea, which is really one of performing a binary search. Much more efficient than removing one feature at the time.

Comment: @Omer: that is a special documentclass which is not part in a TeX distribution. You have at least to provide an URL for this class.

Comment: @Herbert: I inherited the template from another source. It's using "Thesis" document class. I am supposing that is part of the standard tex distribution.

Comment: @Omer: this is no help. There is no `Thesis.cls` and no `thesis.cls` in TeXLive2010.

Comment: I replaced the embedded extensive class source code by a link where you can download the Thesis.cls template and an example thesis document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document is `oneside`, but Thesis.cls expects `twoside`. This can be seen in these two lines of Thesis.cls:

```
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
```

That class uses old-fashioned fancyheading commands. For twoside mode, the optional argument refers to even pages, the mandatory argument refers to odd pages. Here, in oneside mode, `\rhead` overwrites the right mark with the page number.

### Solution:

Change to `twoside` mode or, if you would really like to use `oneside`: call `\lhead` and `\rhead` without optional arguments or use recent commands of fancyhdr.

Note: since you did not post a minimal working example, it took me a lot of time to work out the solution. I've done this because you don't know the importance of minimal working examples yet or don't know how to create them. Have a look at [What is a minimal working example?](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) and at [I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Next time please provide a small compilable code example which shows the problem.

Comment: @Stefan: where do you get the `Thesis.cls`?

Comment: @Herbert: I got it from http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/ , I added that link to the question and removed the embedded class source.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for comments and efforts; I really appreciate them. Actually the reason I placed lot more code, because I was unable to locate the problem.

Comment: @Stefan: I tried both twoside or oneside without \rhead and \lhead options. Unfortunately, it didn't work. You mentioned using recent command of fancyhdr. Could you please elaborate more on that? Which precise commands I could use?

Comment: @Omer: Changing `oneside` to `twoside` immediately works for me. In contrast, if I use `onside`, I could fix it by `\lhead{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}}`. Page numbers could go to the footer because in oneside there`s no space if left head and right head are used for marks already. Just take a look at the [fancyhdr manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for explanation of commands like `fancyhead` etc.

Comment: @Stefan: unfortunately, it didn't work either. The reason I didn't SunilPatel's original CLS because I diverged from it 1.5 year ago and my version is a modified version. That was the reason I put in the whole code...May be you can try with my version of Thesis.cls and then have a look?